# inherited protected defaulted constructor is not accessible

Tags: c++, inheritance, default-constructor, icc

3Trying to compile the code below with ICC return this error:
error #453: protected function "A::A()" (declared at line 10) is not accessible through a "A" pointer or object.

```
class A
{
protected:
    constexpr A() = default;
    ~A() = default;

    A(const A&) = delete;
};

class B
    : protected A
{
public:
    B() = default;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

I found 3 weird ways to make it compilable:

- making the ctor of A public
- removing the deleted copy ctor of A
- replacing "= default;" by "{}" in the ctor of A

I mean, why the h.. ?

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a9cc8a16eaca2659a30defdaa3e68869-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug, since the code is perfectly valid and compiles on other compilers. You might want to file a bug report if that has not happened yet. It seems there are several features involved in confusing the compiler enough to generate the error. Could you, just for completeness, try the following to narrow down the bug: **1** remove the constexpr, **2** try public and private inheritance, **3** replace the `= default` by `{}` in B's ctor **3b** explicitly initialize A in B's ctor. Interesting behavior of ICC :-)

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 don't compile either, however 3b works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm this misbehaviour on v13.1.3 (Linux). This is certainly
a compiler bug as Arne Mertz says: I find that if `A` is
simply provided with an otherwise pointless data member that is initialized
at declaration, the class compiles, e.g.

```
class A
{
protected:
    constexpr A() = default;
    ~A() = default;

    A(const A&) = delete;

private:
    char placate_intel_compiler_bug = 0;
};
```

I don't know what compiler version you have, so don't know
if it supports non-static data member initialization (or if the same
fix would work for you), but if it does then this is a 5th workaround you 
might consider for the merit that its intent is unmistakable.

Removing `constexpr` has no effect on the bug.

Of the 3 workarounds you found the third one, replacing the
defaulted `A::A()` with an explicit `A::A(){}` is the only one
that does not mess with the desired public behaviour of your class.

Arne Mertz's 3b also works for me but that one has the downside of
putting the solution outside class `A`.

If in the real world you have a particular reason for declaring `A::A()`
as `constexpr` then bear in mind, for the 3rd workaround, that if a `constexpr` 
constructor is not `default`-ed then the C++11 Standard § 7.1.5, para 4, 
places rather fiddly constraints on the constructor and its class that could 
make your code more fragile in maintenance. Another possible plus
for the in-your-face 5th workaround.

Comment: I reported the bug here since I didn't know where to do it : [link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler). I think the data member solution is the best to keep A::A()'s compilation behavior as wanted. Even if it consumes more memory, this non copyable base class is used only on big objects.

Comment: That link is I believe the right (and only) place where Joe Public can report bugs. As it's a proprietary toolchain they don't have an open bug-tracking system.